# Is there anything to say that Vaatu's vines were creating Spirit Wilds

Tags: the-legend-of-korra

On the Avatar Wikia , I read that when Vaatu was attacking Republic City, Vaatu was actually creating Spirit Wilds.

[image]

Besides the fact that I couldn't find where I found it on the Avatar Wikia, here is what I want to know

> 1. Do you know where this information may lay in the Avatar Wikia.
> 2. Is it plausible to say that Vaatu was creating Spirit Wilds.
> 3. How do we know it is Spirit Wilds and not just random vegetation.

Answer if you know and please include some **reference** with a good **justified answer** or **comment**.

Comment: Your question revolves around finding a statement made on a community-created website with no guidance to a specific page or timestamp, so even if people were willing to wade through the sea of edits done to a sea of pages, it is still heavily opinion-based. Opinion-based questions usually produce opinion-based answers, which are usually poor answers (at least, on other SE sites). Your second and third sub-questions are looking for opinion-based answers, see above. In short, unless something official states they are Spirit Wilds or not, no-one knows (possibly why the question is unanswered).

Comment: If it was an opinion based question it would have been closed long ago.

Comment: An answer, of sorts - 1. The information is in the sea of edits done to whatever page you haven't referenced ("find this page where I saw this fact for me" would be a more succinct wording). 2. It is plausible (in as much as a world where people control  the elements and spirits are real is plausible), but there is no definitive evidence for either Vaatu creating Spirit Wilds or not. 3. There is no definitive evidence for either Vaatu creating Spirit Wilds or not - hence why no-one has answered this, as it is a question no-one can back up with references, only opinion.

Answer (score 2):

> **The Spirit Wilds partially reemerged following Avatar Korra's decision to keep the spirit portals open in the aftermath of Harmonic Convergence** in 171 AG. Specifically, spirit vines began to grow destructively throughout Republic City, prompting citizens to evacuate from boroughs which became virtually uninhabitable.

It appears from the wikia [here](http://avatar.wikia.com/wiki/Spirit_Wilds#Trivia) under 'Spirit Wilds' that it wasn't particularly *Vaatu* that was creating the spirit wilds, but perhaps Korra's decision to leave the portals open after Harmonic Convergence.

Comment: Best answer I could think of I guess. If anyone thinks of a better one they can add it too.

Comment: They will, but in the meantime I think it's safe to mark this question as "answered."